# How to translate a web page using selenium firefox and chrome driver in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to translate a page into English by using firefox driver and chrome driver. But I am not able to do it.
Here is my code:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium import webdriver    

    #Firefox driver settings
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US, en')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,firefox_profile=profile)

    browser.maximize_window()

    browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

```
#Firefox driver settings
options = Options()
options.headless = True

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US, en')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,firefox_profile=profile)

browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with "en-GB", hope it helps

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-GB')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,firefox_profile=profile)
```